# Stop duplicate values when adding accounts to suitecrm

Tags: php, crm, suitecrm

Im trying to prevent from adding duplicate accounts i have first name and last name fields so far this is what ive got but i cant make it to work. Any experts who knows this ?
appreciate the help.

here's my code:

```
<?php

class ValidateDuplicateRecord {

    //Checks if the account name already exists
    function validateDuplicateRecord( $bean, $event, $arguments ) {

        if( !$bean ) {
            return;
        }

        $accountId = $bean->id;
        $accountFirstName = $bean->pay_fname_c;
        $accountLastName = $bean->pay_lname_c;

        $duplicateAccountMessage = 'Error: An account with name "' . $accountFirstName . '" "' . $accountLastName . '" already exists';

        $accountBean = BeanFactory::getBean( 'Accounts' );

        foreach( $accountBean as $account ) {
            if( $account['id'] !== $accountId && $account['pay_fname_c'] === $accountFirstName && $account['pay_lname_c']) {
                SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage($duplicateAccountMessage);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when this code is triggered? using a logic hook?

Comment: Also where you are getting existing account records and comparing the newly entered record first and last name with that?